# How do I save the pre-populated information on my vforce page when the record is created?

Tags: apex, visualforce, case, user

I have a visualforce page for new cases. It uses an extension, which queries the user object to obtain user information.  The user information is used to 
pre-populate some lookup fields in my visualforce page. Everything works up to this point. However, When I click the save button, the pre-populated fields are
not saved when the case record is created.

Here is my visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" tabstyle="Case" extensions="UserExtension">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:sectionheader title="Case Edit" subtitle="{!if(Case.Id==null,'New Case',Case.CaseNumber)}"></apex:sectionheader>
       <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="casePB" title="Case Edit">
         <apex:pageblockbuttons >
            <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!save}"></apex:commandbutton>
            <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"></apex:commandbutton>
         </apex:pageblockbuttons>
<apex:pageblocksection id="UserInformationPBS" title="User Information">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!CaseObject.Requested_By__c}"></apex:inputfield>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!CaseObject.User_Phone__c}"></apex:inputfield>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!CaseObject.User_Email__c}"></apex:inputfield>
</apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:pageblocksection id="CaseInformationPBS" title="Case Details">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Type}"></apex:inputfield>
        <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>  
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Subject}"></apex:inputfield>
        <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Request_Description__c}"></apex:inputfield>
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Here is my extension

```
public class UserExtension{ 
    public user currentuser{get;set;}
    public Case caseObject {get;set;}

    public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
        currentuser=new User(); 
        currentuser=[Select Id, Name, Email, Phone from User where id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
        caseObject = new Case();
        caseObject.Requested_By__c = currentuser.Id;
        caseObject.User_Phone__c = currentuser.Phone;
        caseObject.User_Email__c= currentuser.Email;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you override the standard `save()` method provided by the `standardController`, clicking the save button on your page will cause the instance of the `Case` object, held by the `standardController` to be saved.

In your extension, you're creating a completely separate instance of `Case`, and pre-populating the fields on that instance.

To get things to behave the way you expect them to, you need to be working on the `Case` instance held by the `standardController`.

The quickest, simplest fix here is a one-line change

```
public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
    currentuser=new User(); 
    currentuser=[Select Id, Name, Email, Phone from User where id=:userinfo.getuserId()];

    // Instead of making a new case, grab the one that already exists from the 
    // controller.
    // This is done by using the getRecord() method.
    // getRecord() returns a generic SObject, so you'll need to explicitly cast
    //   it before use.
    caseObject = (Case)cont.getRecord();
    //caseObject = new Case();
    caseObject.Requested_By__c = currentuser.Id;
    caseObject.User_Phone__c = currentuser.Phone;
    caseObject.User_Email__c= currentuser.Email;
}
```

In terms of coding practice/style. Having your visualforce page refer to the same thing by two different names would probably be a bit confusing. My preference would be to remove `caseObject` from your visualforce page (using `Case` instead). The updated code of your constructor shouldn't need to be changed, though you may want to change `caseObject` to `case` for consistency's sake there as well.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me and guiding me in a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make these changes where you could use this line

```
caseObject = (Case) cont.getRecord();
```

Controller

```
public class UserExtension{ 
    public user currentuser{get;set;}
    public Case caseObject {get;set;}

    public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
        caseObject = (Case) cont.getRecord(); 

        currentuser=[Select Id, Name, Email, Phone from User where id=:userinfo.getuserId()];

        caseObject.Requested_By__c = currentuser.Id;
        caseObject.User_Phone__c = currentuser.Phone;
        caseObject.User_Email__c= currentuser.Email;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that caseObject isn't saved by the standard controller Save. You need to make it reference the standard controller record.

Instantiate your caseObject like this:

`caseObject = (Case)cont.getRecord();`

Then change your VF to always point to Case. For example:

`<apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Requested_By__c}"></apex:inputfield>`